# Filling the empty space left from hidden controls

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is somewhat trivial yet I can't seem to find any standard solution to it.

I have a form where according to the user permissions I show or hide a button+textbox. What happens right now is this:

[image: Can see it]

This is when the user has permission to see/use this. And when he doesn't :

[image: Don't see]

It's not visible - the easy part, but from what I found out, only the `FlowLayoutPanel` offers automatic functionality to hide this empty space and my case is not that.

Comment: It is not recommended to hide controls. The dialog looks different, depending on some condition: this confuses the user. He might ask himself: "Is this really the dialog I wanted to fill out? It looks different". You should deactivate the controls instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Dock` property to `Top` for the label and textbox. That way, when the button and textbox disappear, the layout system will move them up automagically.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if this is a simplified version of your question. If it's only what you describe, whenever you check permissions/hide the relevant controls, you can just reposition the other controls using their Top property.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the control in a `div` and set floating to `float:none`. then, hide the `div` together with its content inside  by setting the `div` display to none `display:none`. Eg;

`<div style="display:none;float:none">
content to hide begin here
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, its very simple, just change the location of that control to the location to the hidden control
and relocate it to the original location when not hiding the hidden control.

```
btn.location=new point(x,y)
```

where **x**, **y** are coordinates of the hidden control shown at winforms.